# MySQL Update Subquery problem

Tags: mysql

I am stuck on an update query that is using a subquery and have not been able to figure it out after reading the manual and trying different ideas. Below is the table & query. Tables Temp_2, Temp_3 & Temp_4 both have 33 rows in them and no null values.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

```
CREATE  TABLE  temp_2 (
    date_value date default NULL, 
    close_adj_value_1 double default NULL);

CREATE  TABLE  temp_3 (
    date_value date default NULL, 
    first_close_adj_value_1 double default NULL);

CREATE  TABLE temp_4 (
    date_value date default NULL,
    pct_return_1 double default NULL);

INSERT INTO temp_4 (date_value) SELECT date_value FROM temp_2;

UPDATE  temp_4
SET     pct_return_1 = 
    (SELECT ((temp_2.close_adj_value_1 / temp_3.first_close_adj_value_1) - 1)
    FROM        temp_2,temp_3
    WHERE temp_2.date_value = temp_3.date_value);
```

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Your subquery seems to be selecting specifically from temp_2 and temp_3 without regard to what it's updating in temp_4.  This would inherently make all rows in temp_4 get the same value.  What exactly is it you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using MySQL, you can employ its multi-table `UPDATE` syntax:

```
UPDATE temp_4
 JOIN temp_2 USING (date_value)
 JOIN temp_3 USING (date_value)
SET temp_4.pct_return_1 = (temp_2.close_adj_value_1 /
                           temp_3.first_close_adj_value_1) - 1;
```

I assume you want to use the `date_value` column to correlate the rows in `temp_4` to the rows in the other tables.

An alternative solution you could use is to insert all the values into an empty `temp_4` table in one go:

```
INSERT INTO temp_4 (date_value, pct_return_1)
  SELECT temp_2.date_value, 
    (temp_2.close_adj_value_1 / temp_3.first_close_adj_value_1) - 1
  FROM temp_2 JOIN temp_3 USING (date_value);
```

Comment: Bill - Thanks for that, that solved my problem. I think I need a note on my monitor to not do anything with SQL before morning coffee. 

Regards,
Eric

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Bill shown below solved my problem:

```
INSERT INTO temp_4 (date_value, pct_return_1)
  SELECT temp_2.date_value, 
    (temp_2.close_adj_value_1 / temp_3.first_close_adj_value_1) - 1
  FROM temp_2 JOIN temp_3 USING (date_value);
```

Comment: Great, I'm glad to help... by the way, it's customary here on StackOverflow to mark the winning answer "accepted."

Comment: Bill - I updated your answer to be accepted. This was my first submission to the site and I was pleasantly surprised with the quality & speed of the response.

Thanks!